# Stackoverflow snippet throws an error but outside it is working

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, mapbox-gl

I have created a stackoverflow snippet inside an answer, but get an error if I am using `map.queryRenderedFeatures()`. Outside the snippet in the `index.html` all works fine. Could it be a CORS problem ? I got no error message except an undefined return. The strange thing is that sometimes it is working in *FullPage* Modus

Here goes my snippet:

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicHJheWVyIiwiYSI6ImI3OGRjZjcyY2JiZTUzODMwZWUxZDdiNjRiMWE4NjI5In0.zETX-x6-XPpAv3zt4MiFwg';

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/prayer/ciub6rm2j004v2iodiej359ox',
    center: [14.5, 47],
    zoom: 6
});



map.on('click', function (e) {
    var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures({
    layers:['roads-bm6ga5'],
    filter: ["==", "id", 1]
});

    document.getElementById('features').innerHTML = '<b>Road with ID</b> ' + features[0].properties.id + ' has the coordinates:' +   
                                                    '<br>' +JSON.stringify(features[0].geometry.coordinates, null, 2);
});

map.on('load', function (e) {
    alert("Click in the map to show coordinates of road with ID 1")
});
```

```css
body { margin:0; padding:0; }
#map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }

#features {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 300px;
        overflow: auto;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    }
    #map canvas {
        cursor: crosshair;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.26.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.26.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>

<div id='map'></div>
<pre id='features'></pre>
```

Comment: `features` is a blank array. So `features[0].properties.id` will throw error. You should check if `features.length>0`

Comment: Hmm thank you ! But features[0] shuld not be empty in this case.. I will take a look why this happens

Comment: Outside the fiddle its never been empty.. Whats the reason for that ? It seems that the query does not work properly inside the fiddle

Comment: @Rajesh Do you know the reason ?

Comment: Not sure but when I created [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/xLj55q94/), there were some extra requests. Mainly `23.vector.pbf`. That can be the cause. You should check if all vectors are available.